# What H means in flywheel dimensions?

Tags: flywheel

I'm looking at a flywheels catalog, the dimensions are like the following:

124T×4H×11mm

I think, T are the number of teeth, the latest number should with the teeth ring width? What the H stands for?

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* the "#H" is the number of holes, and the mm after it is probably the hole size ... that is a total SWAG. There's another measure which goes with it, usually the OD (outside diameter). I believe this is the outside diameter of the clutch disk which goes on it, but not quite sure. This is all a guess, so leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Yes, I just found out T and H, but not the mm. H are the number of holes...